# PHP - PCLZIP adding file from string

Tags: php, zip, pclzip

PCLZIP is a great library, but unfortunately it is poorly documented.
I am using it in order to support also servers where ZipArchive is disabled (or php version not supported)

I have a function to add uploaded files (one by one) to a ZIP archive.
If the archive is not existing, it creates one, if the archive exists, it just adds the new files.

The problem I have is with a function adding a TXT file, that is based on the Comments from the archive. (the function reads the comments that were previously prepared, and should create a TXT file from string and insert into the archive.)

I can not seem to find a function to OVERWRITE a file from string (Or I do not know how to use it ).

I can create it with   `PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_NAME` ,but somehow, when I run the function, it creates a new `.txt` file (with  the same filename!) every time it adds a file to the archive (as opposed to OVERWRITE the existing one)
I tried to use `PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_NEW_FULL_NAME` - but I can not find where to give it the parameters to WHICH file it needs to overwrite ..

The function is here : (sorry if it is long..)

```
    $archive = new PclZip($zipname);

        if (!file_exists($zipname)){  //The Archive already exists - let´s just ADD new files.


            $comment = $comment_head . $comment_add ;

            $string_content = $comment;

            $v_list = $archive->create($file,
                                        PCLZIP_OPT_ADD_PATH, $sitename,
                                        PCLZIP_OPT_COMMENT, $comment,
                                        PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_ALL_PATH);

                                        $prop = $archive->properties();
                                        $prop = $prop['comment'];
                                        if (!$prop) {$prop = $comment;}

            $list = $archive->add(array(
                                   array( 
                                   PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_NAME => $string_file,
                                   PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_CONTENT => $prop,
                                   PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_NEW_FULL_NAME => $string_file
                                         )
                                   )
                                   );


                      if ($v_list == 0) {
                        die("Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
                      }


        } else { 

// No Archive already exists - Create with new file .

        $comment_add =  $meta['file'] . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL ;/*.$comment_foot*/ ;

        $b_list = $archive->add($file,
                                    PCLZIP_OPT_ADD_PATH, $sitename,
                                    PCLZIP_OPT_ADD_COMMENT, $comment_add,
                                    PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_ALL_PATH);

                                $prop = $archive->properties();
                                        $prop = $prop['comment'];
                                        if (!$prop) {$prop = $comment;}

            $list_6 = $archive->add(array(
                                   array( PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_NAME => $string_file,
                                        PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_CONTENT => $prop
                                         )
                                   )
                                   );

                  if ($b_list == 0) {
                    die("Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
                  }

      }
```

So - anyone knows how to OVERWRITE a file from string (and not from file..) with PCLzip ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$archive = new PclZip("archive.zip");
$v_filename = "new_file.txt";
$v_content = "This is the content of file one\nHello second line";
$list = $archive->create(array(
                               array( PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_NAME => $v_filename,
                                      PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_CONTENT => $v_content
                                     )
                               )
                         );
if ($list == 0) {
  die("ERROR : '".$archive->errorInfo(true)."'");
}
```

http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/news/3-pclzip-26